# Angularjs not load css first when using stateprovider?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have use $stateProvider for redirect to page and when page redirect at that time i have render also css but issue is that first plain html load after that css files style sheet apply. any one idea about that how to fix that my issue....

My code below like that

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        "body": {
            templateUrl: '../template/home.html',
            controller: 'HomegCtrl'
        }
    },
    css: [{
        href: '../css/home.css'
    }, {
        href: '../css/footer.css'
    }]
})
```

Comment: Are you using the angular-css library to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give me reference url or something so i can get it...?

Comment: Are you using this library: https://github.com/castillo-io/angular-css

Comment: I have used that library dear but not getting output...!